# What does MATLAB's estimateUncalibratedRectification do expressed mathematically ? What does it calculate exactly?

Tags: matlab, geometry, computer-vision, matlab-cvst, projection-matrix

What does MATLAB's [estimateUncalibratedRectification](http://se.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/estimateuncalibratedrectification.html) do in mathematical/geometrical terms ?

What does it calculate exactly ?

As far as I understand, if the camera parameters are unknown then **only** the fundamental matrix can be computed from two images, **not** the essential matrix.

So, as far as I understand, `estimateUncalibratedRectification`'s result should be ambiguous up to some kind of a transformation `T` because the fundamental matrix - that can be computed from two images if the camera's intrinsic parameters are not known - is ambiguous up to an arbitrary projective transformation.

Is this correct ?

My guess is that `estimateUncalibratedRectification` computes a projective transformation `P1` for `image1` and another projective transformation `P2` for `image2` in such a way that when using these two transformations (`P1` and `P2`) on the corresponding images then the resulting images (`R1` and `R2`) will be rectified in the sense that the corresponding epipolar lines will be in the same rows, as shown in the image below.

[image]

My question is: how ambiguous is this result ?
My feeling is that the resulting transformations `P1` and `P2` are ambiguous up to some transformation `T` but I don't really see what this `T` can be.

Could someone please explain how `estimateUncalibratedRectification` works conceptually/mathematically/geometrically  and also tell what `T` can be ?

In other words, **what is the transformation** `T` which when applied to `R1` and `R2` will result in an image pair `TR1` and `TR2` which will have the same rectified property as `R1` and `R2`, namely that corresponding epipolar lines appear in matching rows in `TR1` and `TR2`, just like they do in `R1` and `R2`?

What is this `T` ? Is there such a `T` ?

PS.: I have read the code of `estimateUncalibratedRectification.m` before posting this question but it made me no wiser.

Comment: I didn't really used this approach in practice, but you can read the theoretically background in the paper below: _Hartley, R.I., Theory and Practice of Projective Rectification. IJCV 35 2, pp 115-127 (1999)_ [PDF](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.6.1107&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: Me again, and think about it that the function outputs not the rectification transformations in the object (3D) space, but as you wrote the planar perspective transformations encoded by the homography matrices `T1` and `T2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot about the info Kornel !

Comment: What do you mean by `T1` and `T2` ? They meant to transform what to what ?

Comment: Hmm... my gut feeling is that `T1` transforms from the original first image `image1` to a transformed, rectified first image `R1`. Isn't that right ? I don't quite understand what do you mean by switching from the first image to the second image ?

Comment: ahh, that's my fault sorry, you are right. So `T1` transforms from the original image to the rectified version of it. The rest of my comment are invalid, I delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the intrinsics are not known, the result is ambiguous up to a projective transformation. In other words, if you use `estimateUncalibratedRectification` to rectify a pair of images, and then compute disparity and do the 3D reconstruction, then you will reconstruct the 3D scene up to a projective transformation. Straight lines will be straight, parallel lines will be parallel, but your angles and sizes will likely be wrong.

To determine what that projective transformation is, you would need more information. If you know the camera intrinsics, then you get up to scale reconstruction. In other words you get the correct angles and relative sizes. To get the correct scale you would either need to know the baseline (distance between the cameras) or the size of some reference object in the scene.

The more straight-forward way to approach this is to calibrate your cameras using the Camera Calibrator app or the Stereo Camera Calibrator app.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. What is the value of `estimateUncalibratedRectification` at all then? Why was it implemented in the first place ? Practically, IMHO, it is not good for anything if the 3D reconstruction is ambiguous up to projective transformation.

Comment: @jhegedus, sometimes a projective reconstruction is all you need. E. g. if you only need to know what's in front of what. Also, as I said, you can use `estimateUncalibratedRectification` to get up-to-scale reconstruction, if you know the intrinsics. You can also use the resulting rectification as an intermediate step for further calibration of your system or for better reconstruction.

Comment: @jhegedus, not to mention that `estimateUncalibratedRectification` lets you create cool stereo anaglyphs that you can look at with stereo glasses. :)